# ESMs are always file-based

Tags: javascript

****ES Modules****

**First, there’s no wrapping function to define a module. The
wrapping context is a file. ESMs are always file-based; one
file, one module.**

I found this sentence from "you don't know js by kyle simpson".What is he meant by ESMs are always file-based; one file, one module.Does that mean one java script file can only contains one module

Comment: Contrast this with [this proposal](//github.com/tc39/proposal-js-module-blocks).

Comment: In CommonJS modules, each javascript file is wrapped in a wrapper function to define a module; in ESM, there is no wrapper function. That is what that statement means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean one java script file can only contains one module

Yes. Every JavaScript module file contains exactly one module. You can't have a module file with more than one module in it.

Comment: function example1 () {
    return 'example 1'
}

  function example2 () {
    return 'example 2'
}

module.exports.example1 = example1;
module.exports.example2 = example2;

do you mean this is impossible.Here I define two modules in single filr

Comment: @KasunWickramanayake What? Is that supposed to be an ES module file? That's CommonJS.

Comment: example.js
----------------
export const example1 = async () => {
   return 'example 1'
}

export const example2 = async () => {
   return 'example 2'
}


// other file
import { example1, example2 } from '../../example'
return example1()

sorry this my example.I m new to java script.So in this example we I have two exports.Does it considers as two different module?

Comment: There are two modules: `example.js`, which exports two things (`example1` and `example2`) and the other file, which exports nothing, but imports those things.